# "Скорбеть" или "скорбить"?

Tags: орфография, фонетика

Как правильно:"скорбеть" или "скорбить"?
С одной стороны, "он воскорбел", с другой - глагол "оскорбить".

Answer (score 2):

**Скорбеть** - непереходный отыменный глагол, суффикс Е (скорбеть самому).

Глагола "скорбить" нет, а глагол **оскорбить** - переходный отыменный глагол, суффикс И (обидеть кого-то).

Таким образом, **переходность отыменных глаголов может обозначаться с помощью суффиксов Е/И**:  леденеть (самому, непереходный глагол) – леденить (кого-то, переходный глагол).  Также: светлеть - осветлить, темнеть - затемнить.

Comment: И от какого "имени" *оскорбить*?

Comment: Отыменность - еще ладно, в основе-то все равно "скорбь" а вот переходность-то  здесь вторична. Тут значения разные по семантики корневого морфа. Поэтому говорить о паре можно только относительно. .

Comment: Из Правил Лопатина § 63. -е(ть), -и(ть). Различаются глаголы на -еть и -ить. Глаголы на -еть  — непереходные I спряжения — имеют значение 'стать каким-нибудь, приобрести признак', напр.: обессилеть, обессилею 'стать бессильным, лишиться силы', обездушеть, посуроветь 'стать суровым'. Глаголы на -ить =— переходные II спряжения — имеют значение 'сделать каким-нибудь, наделить признаком', напр.: обессилить, обессилю 'сделать кого-нибудь бессильным, лишить силы', обезболить, обезвредить, обездушить, ослабить.

Comment: Ср. те же суффиксы под ударением в глаголах гипа (по)беле́ть и (по)бели́ть, (о)слабе́ть, (раз)весели́ть.

Comment: Это сообщение заслуживало минуса, удаленного модератором. Причина изложена в комментарии. Переходность - признак (не абсолютный), но не причина.

Comment: почему морф корневой, если -ить и -еть - это аффиксальные морфы? а корневой морф-то один и тот же

Answer (score 1):

А это разные глаголы, от разных основ-образующих. Суффикс меняет смысл. 
Поэтому: ***скорбеть*** - и только так.

*Оскорбить-оскорбил* - "кого-что", переходный глагол.
*Скорбеть-скробел, воскорбеть-воскорбел* - в лучшем случае только "по кому/ком". Вот если бы "скорбить - кого", то и было бы "скорбить".

Есть еще более явные подобные пары.

*Чернить* - кого.
*Чернеть* - сам по себе.

*Обезножить* - кого.
*Обезножеть* - стать безногим, лишенным возможности ходить.

Ну и прочее. Обычно эта разница хорошо понимается на интуитивном уровне.

Во всех таких случаях, когда есть подозрение на пару, смотрите смысл. 
Если это что-то свое, непрямого действия, то *-еть, -ел*.
Если действие переносится кого, глагол переходный, *-ить, -ил*.

(+) 
*Вообще это тема отдельного исследования для интересующихся исторической грамматикой русского глагола. Такое разделение функций глагольного суффикса явно не случайно. Есть подозрение, что корни надо искать во временах грамматики так называемого "паратактического строя" и бытности инфинитива особой формой отглагольного существительного: Подобное разделение функций характерно для номинативных (именных) суффиксов. Но здесь вряд ли уместно развивать эту тему, да и не специалист я.*